# apt: keep only pkgcache.bin, delete srcpkgcache.bin

Tags: debian, apt, package-management

How to disable `srcpkgcache.bin` without disabling `pkgcache.bin` (which has the extremely annoying effect of breaking `apt install` bash completion)? I've tried

```
#Dir::Cache::pkgcache "";
Dir::Cache::srcpkgcache "";
```

but then `apt` deletes `pkgcache.bin` after each `apt install`. If I comment out both lines, then both caches are kept (but I don't want the src cache).

I've experimented with both `apt` and `apt-get`, but it doesn't matter.